# Localization guide

Tags: formatting, localization

I am trying to find a concise guide to localization settings by language or country. By this I mean the rules and example of how to format dates, numbers and currencies in each language or country.

Where can I find such a guide?

Comment: Great that you are applying localised standards. Will you still allow users to change their settings? happens often enough that someone has different preferences than most common in their region.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at these links about date, time, currency and number formatting:

[**Date format by country**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)

[**Currency designators and country codes (ISO 4217)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217)

[**Number formatting**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator)

Comment: Maybe add time formatting?
Preferred start day of the week? Would be cool if we can add more things people are less likely to think about :)

Comment: Thanks, but the 2nd link does not contain currency formats.